# Scam mail beeing sent to my classified posters

Tags: php, mysql, html, security, email

I have a classifieds website, and anybody may view the classifieds which people post.

People don't need to be a member or anything to view, or contact a poster.

The problem I have today is that people receive alot of scam-mail from others, who intend to scam them off their money etc...

The process of sending an email to a poster, is to click "Email Poster" and fill out the form.
The form then submits to a php page, which checks against a database that the same message hasn't been sent from the same IP within the last hour, just as a spam measure.

Also I do check so the same ip doesn't send messages on the same classified more than twice, regardless of text, within 10 minutes.

I have some other filters as well, but they don't help 100%.

They still manage to send out one email every hour, my god they are persistent.

Is there any other method to 100% prevent these scam mails? Or do I simply have to live with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add a captcha challenge to your form,
  such as reCAPTCHA.
- You could ban the IP from sending any
  emails together if they hit the
  sending limit three times in a row.
- You could require the sender to click
  a confirmation link that is sent to
  their own email, before the recipient
  receives their email.

Taking the comments into consideration, I'll add more ways to battle them.

- Require senders to connect with a
  well know social site (eg. Facebook)
  to authenticate themselves.
- Block entire countries from sending emails - some countries have a lot more scammers than others.
- Alternatively only allow people to
  send email to recipients from the
  same   country. (ie. User posts
  classified  from USA, then only IPs
  from USA can     respond)

Comment: **"The problem I have today is that people receive alot of scam-mail from others, who intend to scam them off their money"** How do you want to stop scammers with CAPTCHAs and confirmation links? I assume they can read and click, don't they?

Comment: You are aware that scammers usually doesn't do all this by hand?

Comment: They often do. And even if they don't they use captcha farms these days.

Comment: It would be more correct to say "most of the scammer doesn't do this by hand", these paid services exists, but are used only by a small slice of the spammers (since it costs money).

Comment: abloodywar: Any ideas how to convert an IP to a Country? Is there such a free database which is updated all the time, and reliable? It has to be free btw.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [CAPTCHAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) to prevent bots abusing your system?

Comment: This is the same question I asked @abloodywar: How do you want to stop scammers with CAPTCHAs and confirmation links? I assume they can read and click, don't they? Also if you are talking about bots and not people that the original poster was asking about, then [google for captcha farms](http://www.google.com/search?q=captcha+farms) and watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ic1LToPsro) and [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLgvrsAoPeE).

Comment: @Zed: This type of attacks are reserved for high profile target. A spammer will never waste his money against a no-one's site like the asker's (and yes, he is a no-one from the spammer point of view). A good CAPTCHA can hold most of the spammer at bay. And using AKISMET could improve the effectiveness even more (but I'm not really sure about this). Having 1 spam vs 10000 good is better then 10 spam vs 1 good, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using something like the [Akismet API](http://akismet.com/development/api/)? Obviously it depends on the kind of spam but that might help.